# How to catch that finger still on button if there is no movements?

Tags: android, gesture, ontouchlistener, android-touch-event

I am using `OnTouchListener()` and I wanted to know if there are any options to catch that finger still on the button, in `ACTION_MOVE` mode when the finger is not moving. I mean I understand that `ACTION_MOVE` triggered almost constantly. But when I checked it a few times I received that it could take more than second to receive `ACTION_MOVE` after another. This is too long. 
So the question is if it possible to trigger `ACTION_MOVE` with custom frequency.
Or maybe it is possible to make `onLongClick()` with custom long click time?

Or maybe there is another action, that could help me?